# Power Supply Rating versus Graphics Card requirement

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

Windows 8.1 64 bit

Lepa N500 Power supply

GTX Geforce 650 ti boost

My Lepa N500 Power supply is rated at 500 watts. I read some about PSU's and it says that the overall rating isn't really what matters. Apparently, for Graphics Card requirements, one should check the line 12? rating. On my power supply it is 408 Watts.

IF NVIDIA says that the GTX Geforce 650 Ti Boost requires 450 Watts, does this mean that my 500 watt power supply is enough? Or should I be comparing 450 Watts to 408 Watts, thus seeing that my psu can't support my graphics card?

My computer ran for a whole year using this PSU and Graphics card but now I am having a problem where my computer will shutdown turn off and restart at the lock screen and I am given critical event 41 Kernel-Power in my event logs.

Could this mean that my power supply is too weak? Why did my computer work for a whole year before this happened?

NOTE: Computer will run in Safe Mode using the ONBOARD video card. Not the NVIDIA card

Comment: The `Geforce 650 Ti` doesn't require 450 watts.  If the power supply was working with the graphics card you have for over a year, and problems just surfaced, then the power supply has simply failed.  It is more powerful enough to handle the card in question which uses 150W at full load at best.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the proper display drivers installed.  How long have you had this problem, what changed from the time it was working to the time its not working, that infnomration is important.

Answer (score 0):

If your PS doesn't have some sort of malfunction, then you should be pretty sure that it isn't a cause of your problems. Lepa G 500 W is actually the Enermax MODU87+. This is one of the best in class PS. What nVidia recommends is the rated power of the Power Supply unit. Most id not all modern PS are based on 12V and all other voltages derives from the 12V so basically you can have almost full rated power on 12V rail(s).

Thermal and Power Specs:

97C Maximum GPU Temperature (in C)

**134W** Maximum Graphics Card Power (W)

450W Minimum System Power Requirement (W)

One 6-pinSupplementary Power Connectors

You can try with another PS and if you still have the same issues you should look somewhere else for the problem, rather than PS.

If you changed anything recently, like updating BIOS, drivers etc. or you have changed some hardware, I suggest that you check this first

I just sow your EDIT... Check the nVidia drivers.

Comment: If my Video card requires 450 Watts, and my Processor requires, say 70 watts, then does that mean I need at least 520 Watts? Is that how it works?

Comment: The review of Enermax power supplies does not give me the impression they are "best in class" contender.

Comment: I was talking about this particular PS
http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/LEPA-G-500-W-Power-Supply-Review/1199/10

Comment: @Tyler P Maximum power that your VGA drawn is 134W according to nVidia specs.

Comment: @TylerP Your graphics card **doesn't** require 450 W. It's the *Minimum **System** Power Requirement*, not *Minimum **GPU** Power Requirement*.

Comment: I strongly suggest you eliminate the statement that its the "best in class" a power supply released in 2011 isn't the best in anything.  It is at best an average power supply, even when it was released, compared to what eventually came out in 2011.  ( I have problems with valid answers being scuffed up by an opinion ).

Comment: @Ramhound What you just wrote is only YOUR opinion and perception and nothing else. Go to Hardware Secrets and you can comment that their review is bad. You don't have to argue with me. Maybe you have more sophisticated equipment than HW Secrets so you can challenge their results. 2011 is not old PS

Comment: It was written 3 years and 11 months ago.  If hardware in the article  was alive it would be in a retirement home and complaining about how his great-grand children didn't visit him.  I was trying to improve the question so it only stuck to the non-opinionated facts.

Comment: Well. I can agree with you, but in your answers I see only opinions and not the facts... no numbers, no references, nothing that can support what you stand for